# Color dialog and other dialogs not opening in ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using custom CKEditor(version:4.7.8) plugin in modal popup using jQuery.
It is working fine in chrome and FF but in IE 10 when I am going to select font color or back color then dialog box get flicker. It doesn't keep open to select color.

This is reported bug which was fixed but still it doesnt seems to be.

Is anyone facing same issue. any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Added following code to the page.

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
        _allowInteraction: function (event) {
            if (this._super(event)) {
                return true;
            }

            // address interaction issues with general iframes with the dialog
            if (event.target.ownerDocument != this.document[0]) {
                return true;
            }

            // address interaction issues with dialog window
            if ($(event.target).closest(".cke_dialog").length) {
                return true;
            }

            // address interaction issues with iframe based drop downs in IE
            if ($(event.target).closest(".cke").length) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

It is working now !!!1